# bootstrap tags input template code not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, pug, bootstrap-tags-input

I trying to make a "tags input" in one of my form field (equipment), and i tried the code from https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/exqd3#comments
(i have extend this pug from a layout.pug and also included the .js and .css code from the above website)
I didn't know if it is because i imported the link/script into the wrong place? or there is a clash with the plug-in versions.

```
    extends ../layout
    block header
        title Host Studio
        script(src = "https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js")
        script(src = "tag.js")
        style
            include addStudio.css
            include tag.css

        link(href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css")
        script(src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")

   block content
   div
    h1 Host a studio
    form.form-default(action='/studio_register' method='POST')
        div.cred
            label( style="padding-right: 20px;") Equipment
            br
            input#form-tags-1(type ='text' value='guitar,mic,amp'  name='tags-1' required='')


        button(type='submit' style="margin-left: 41%;") Register Studio
```

and my layout.pug is:

```
    doctype html
    html(lang='en')
       head
    // Required meta tags
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge")
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no')


    title SimplyRecord                  

    // CSS Link
    //link(rel='stylesheet', href=../public/stylesheets/home)

    // Using Bootstrap 4
    // Bootstrap CSS
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous")

    // our custom css stylesheet
    style
        include index.css

body
    block header
    // Webpage Background Gradient - The entire page needs to be within this div
    #Background-Gradient
        block content
        include footer


    // Using Bootstrap 4   
    // jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS
    script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous")
    script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous")
    script(src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous")
```

(sorry for some wrong indentation, changed when copied over)

the page is able to load with no error, just not applying the "tags format"

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DWzT.png)

Comment: Did you check for any errors in the console after the server side page is rendered on your browser?

Comment: there is no error, the page is able to load, just not applying the "tags" format

Comment: Please check the Pug indentation in your code locally and ensure the code in the question matches it. As it is presented now, there are many indentation errors.